# Grid View Unbalance Issue (Image make some text hidden)

Tags: android

http://upload.lsforum.net/users/public/h10504testj63.jpg

I want to show 11 icon on the home menu of my application, but now i have a trouble.
On row 1, Item3 is too long so that row 2 giving some place for display Item3.
On row 2, Item4 is also too long but row 3 not giving some place for display Item4.

### There is my code i tried, activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

<GridView   
    android:id="@+id/MenuItemGrid"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:columnWidth="88dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:numColumns="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

### And it is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int[] ItemImage = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,                R.drawable.ic_launcher,  
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
        R.drawable.ic_launcher ,R.drawable.ic_launcher };  

    private String[] ItemText = {   "Test Long Item 1", "Test Long Item 2", "Test Long Item 333333333333", 
            "Test Long Item 4444444444444", "Test Long Item 5", "Test Long Item 6",
            "Test Long Item 7", "Test Long Item 8", "Test Long Item 9",
            "Test Long Item 10", "Test Long Item 11"};  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView MenuItemGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.MenuItemGrid);  

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> ItemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();  

        for (int i = 0; i < ItemImage.length; i++) {  
            HashMap<String, Object> ItemMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
            ItemMap.put("ItemImage", ItemImage[i]);  
            ItemMap.put("ItemText", ItemText[i]);  
            ItemList.add(ItemMap);  
        } 

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, ItemList,  
        R.layout.items, new String[] { "ItemImage", "ItemText" }, new int[] {  
        R.id.image, R.id.title });  

        MenuItemGrid.setAdapter(simpleAdapter); 
    }

}
```

---

### items.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"     
    android:orientation="vertical" >  

<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/image"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />  

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/title"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

Comment: http://upload.lsforum.net/users/public/f43742testgridr63.jpg
The problem still not solve

Comment: http://upload.lsforum.net/users/public/r28539testgrid2f63.jpg
This picture may be shown the issue more obvious